# Positive square root of a complex number using cmath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm being passed a real number and an imaginary number, x and y to make up a complex number.

Given this, I have a method sqrt where I need to find a positive square root of a complex number. The constructor name is given as ComplexS that is returned.
I know I am supposed to use cmath but how would I do it?

```
    def sqrt(self):
        sqrtnum = self.cmath.sqrt()

        return ComplexS(?, ?)
```

Comment: "I know I am supposed to use cmath" - are you? Because if you're using `cmath`, you're using Python's built-in complex number type, which makes writing your own complex number type kind of weird.

Comment: Define "a positive square root of a complex number". Positive and negative are not atttributes of complex numbers as far as I know. They have attributes like "on the real axis" (i.e. imaginary part 0), "on the imaginary axis" (i.e. real part 0). There is however never a square root of a complex number with non-0 imaginary part which has 0 imaginary part.

Answer (score -1):

```
import cmath

def sqrt(z):
    sqrtnum = cmath.sqrt(z) 
    return sqrtnum

print (sqrt(3+2j))

print (sqrt(4))
```

Output:

```
(1.8173540210239707+0.5502505227003375j)
(2+0j)
```

Comment: Your `sqrt` is just a pass-through wrapper for `cmath.sqrt`. It doesn't add or change any functionality, and it has no reason to exist. Also, this answer ignores the `ComplexS` class the questioner is apparently supposed to be using.

Comment: The OP wants to use cmath in a function. It may be quite useless I concede. Here I just made minimal changes to provide the OP with what he seems to request for. For the ComplexS class you're right, however difficult to answer that part with the level of details in the question.  I hope that is clear ;)